# Styling the HTML tag in a web document

Tags: html, css

is it good Coding Practice to add style to the `<html>` tag of a web document?

why should you not style the `<html>` tag of a web document?

I ask this because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841093/1214743) on a StackOverflow question.
Personally I don't think this is good coding practice.

is there a WC3 standard that says this is good/bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the matter of [cross-browser inconsistencies](http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/) between the `<html>` tag and the `<div>` tag, with the `<div>` having more consistent behavior. The [w3c recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) that you style the `<body>` tag rather than the `<html>` tag. Much of this again has to do with [modern browser behavior](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html):

> Many web developers do not understand the difference between applying
>   style to the body element versus the html element. Most of the time
>   these authors will apply style only to the body element; when that's
>   not sufficient, they'll spam all sorts of styles on both html and body
>   until the page happens to look correct.
>
> The confusion is understandable. In the beginning, both were treated
>   similarly, with (now-deprecated) attributes like bgcolor being applied
>   to the body tag, affecting the whole page.
>
> This article attempts to enlighten you, Web Developer, to fully grok
>   how these two elements are used in modern web browsers.

Comment: maybe I should rephrase the question, I completely agree with what you are saying, but what I want to know is " should you style the `<html>` tag? "

Comment: added additional reasoning and sources

Comment: I think he means "Should you use html as a selector (in your CSS file)?", not "Should you put style rules in your html file".

Comment: Fixed and shortened to better focus on the question at hand.

Comment: I am going to give this some time to attract other answers.